# Inline core dump generation from a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, coredump

In the course of development of some application we came to a need of possibly getting a complete core dump without completely stopping execution of a program completely.

Granted there are conditions that generate core dump where continuation may not be safely possible but we are not talking about memory corruption, and such.

What I am looking to do is send a signal to the program and generate a complete core without or minimally impacting program execution

Is this possible?  If so how?

Comment: This is OS specific.  What OS?

Comment: You could `fork` and then `abort` the other process.

Comment: What do you mean by a core dump? A full memory dump? A stack trace?

Comment: @n.m. Nice idea. I don't think it's possible to core dump a single process without something like `SIGABRT`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Full memory dump.

Comment: @Gene I am looking for all UNIX and like flavors, but primary use is Solaris and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this Google library, it might help: http://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper/

> The coredumper library can be compiled into applications to create
>   core dumps of the running program -- without terminating.

Answer (score 0):

[Coredumpber](http://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper/) is for Linux and obviously a great idea if that's your OS.

For other Posix-like systems, something like this ought to work fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <process.h>

// Fork and abort for a core dump. This process keeps running.
if (fork() == 0) abort();
```

Of course the environment must be set to dump core on `SIGABRT`.  You could also try `raise(SIGTERM)`, which is like `kill -9`.